# How to execute a function when setTimeout is complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In this example gamplay() function is executed when the page is loaded, this triggers  playPattern() within the if statement. The playPattern accepts an array and calls a setTimeout on each element in the array which executes the playAudio for that element. PlayAudio adds a class to a an element and play's an audio file.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    function playPattern(arr){
        var patternIDs = {
            0: 'blue',
            1: 'green',
            2: 'red',
            3: 'yellow'
        }
        for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
            var myTimer = setTimeout(playAudio, 1000*x, patternIDs[arr[x]]);        
        }
        clearTimeout(myTimer);

    }//Plays a sequence of audio depending on the array values
    function playAudio(id){
        switch (id){
            case 'blue':
                document.getElementById('idBtnBlue').classList.add('btn--blue__highlight');
                document.getElementById('sound1').play();   
                break;
            case 'red':
                document.getElementById('idBtnRed').classList.add('btn--red__highlight');
                document.getElementById('sound2').play();           
                break;
            case 'green':
                document.getElementById('idBtnGreen').classList.add('btn--green__highlight');
                document.getElementById('sound3').play();           
                break;
            case 'yellow':
                document.getElementById('idBtnYellow').classList.add('btn--yellow__highlight') ;
                document.getElementById('sound4').play();       
                break;
        }
    }//Play audio 
  function removeHighlight(){
        document.getElementById('idBtnBlue').classList.remove('btn--blue__highlight');
        document.getElementById('idBtnRed').classList.remove('btn--red__highlight');
        document.getElementById('idBtnGreen').classList.remove('btn--green__highlight');
        document.getElementById('idBtnYellow').classList.remove('btn--yellow__highlight');
    }//Remove Highlight
    function gamePlay(){
        var simonArr = [];
        var userArr = [];
        var testArr = [3, 2, 0, 1, 3];

        if(strict){
            playPattern(testArr);       

        }
        else{
            playPattern(testArr);
        }
        removeHighlight();
    }//main gameplay

  gamePlay(); //Start game play 
});
```

What I want to do is call removeHighlight() once all the elements in the array have been played.

I've tried to call  removeHighlight() after the for loop in playPattern or after the if statement is done in the gameplay() but then realized that the function was being called before the highlight was even being added.

Thank you any help is appreciated. 
[Codepen](http://codepen.io/Froy/pen/xdYEBj?editors=0010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass additional parameter to mark last item, then call function inside playAudio:

```
var myTimer = setTimeout(playAudio, 1000*x, patternIDs[val],x==arr.length-1);
```

[pen](http://codepen.io/mackie_pl/pen/XRBxJJ?editors=0010)

or, probably the easiest way - call the function directly with:

```
setTimeout(removeHighlight, 1000*(arr.length-1));
```

right before end of playPattern().

Also, hope you are aware that clearTimeout() is always destroying your 1st call, unless declaring the variable inside forEach scope.

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of promises that resolve on audio elements `onended` event. Then use `Promise.all(array).then( /* un highlight function reference*/)`  to clear the highlights when all the promises have resolved.

```
const patternNames = "blue,green,red,yellow".split(",");
const patternElements = patterNames.map(name => document.getElementById("idBtn" + name[0].toUpperCase() + name.substr(1)) );
function playPattern(arr){
    function playAudio(id, time){
        return new Promise((resolve) => {  // create a promise to play audio at time 
            setTimeout(() => {
                var audioElement;
                patternElements[id].classList.add("btn--" + patternNames[id] + "__highlight");
                (audioElement = document.getElementById("sound" + (id + 1))).play();   
                audioElement.onended = resolve;
            },time);
         });
    }
    Promise.all(patternNames.map((name, i) => playAudio(i, i * 1000))).then(() => { // when all sounds play then 
                                                                                    // clear all highlights
        patternElements.forEach((name, i) => patternElements[i].classList.remove("btn--" + patternNames[i] + "__highlight"));
    })
} 
playPattern([1,2,3,0,2,1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `setTimeout` function is asynchronous, and so your `playPattern` function will actually return before any of the `playAudio` delayed calls have been made.

This means that `removeHighlight` will also be called before any of the timeout callbacks have fired. If you want to do something when all the sounds have played, you'll need a way to manage your asynchronous function calls, and fire a callback when these have all completed.

I like to use the wonderful [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library to do this type of stuff, but you could also achieve something similar with Promises. With it, you would rewrite your `playPattern` function as follows:

```
function playPattern (arr, done) {
  var patternIDs = {
    0: 'blue',
    1: 'green',
    2: 'red',
    3: 'yellow'
  }

  var iteratee = function (item, i, cb) {
    setTimeout(function (id) {
      playAudio(id)
      cb()
    }, 1000 * i, patternIDs[arr[i]])
  }

  async.eachOf(arr, iteratee, done)
}
```

Now, when you call `playPattern`, you can pass in a function as the second argument which will only be called once all of the `setTimeout` delayed calls have completed. You can rewrite your `gamePlay` function as follows:

```
function gamePlay () {
  var testArr = [3, 2, 0, 1, 3]

  playPattern(testArray, removeHighlight)
}
```